# How to use Common Lisp libraries of dex, plump, and clss to extract the title of a web page?

Tags: http, common-lisp, html-parsing

I am using Emacs, Slime, and SBCL to develop Common Lisp in a Desktop PC running NixOS.

In addition, I am using the libraries [dex](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador), [plump](https://quickref.common-lisp.net/clss.html), and [clss](https://github.com/Shinmera/plump) to extract the title of a webpage. Thus, I did:

```lisp
CL-USER> (clss:select "title" (plump:parse  (dex:get "http://www.pdelfino.com.br")))
#(#<PLUMP-DOM:ELEMENT title {1009C488E3}>)
```

I was expecting: "Pedro Delfino".

Instead, I got the object:

```lisp
#(#<PLUMP-DOM:ELEMENT title {1009C488E3}>)
```

If I describe the object it does not help me finding the value I want:

```lisp
CL-USER> (clss:select "title" (plump:parse  (dex:get "http://www.pdelfino.com.br")))
#(#<PLUMP-DOM:ELEMENT title {100A9888E3}>)
CL-USER> (describe *)
#(#<PLUMP-DOM:ELEMENT title {100A9888E3}>)
  [vector]

Element-type: T
Fill-pointer: 1
Size: 10
Adjustable: yes
Displaced: no
Storage vector: #<(SIMPLE-VECTOR 10) {100A9B65BF}>
; No value
CL-USER>
```

Where is the value that I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask plump to return the text inside the HTML node with `plump:text`. It accepts one node, and not an array (returned by `clss:select`), so you have to use `aref` to get the first one.

```lisp
(plump:text (aref  
   (clss:select "title" (plump:parse  
     (dex:get "http://www.pdelfino.com.br"))) 
   0))
```

`plump:serialize` would return the HTML content (useful to inspect the results).

You can also use CLSS and Plump together at the same time by using LQuery. https://shinmera.github.io/lquery/ We need to parse the HTML with `initialize`, then we use `$` as in `(lquery:$ <document> "selector")`. We can add `(text)` or `(serialize)` as last arguments.

```lisp
(defparameter *PDELFINO-PARSED* (lquery:$ (initialize (dex:get "http://www.pdelfino.com.br"))))

(lquery:$ *PDELFINO-PARSED* "title")
#(#<PLUMP-DOM:ELEMENT title {1008645923}>)

CIEL-USER> (lquery:$ *PDELFINO-PARSED* "title" (text))
#("Pedro Delfino")

CIEL-USER> (aref * 0)
"Pedro Delfino"

CIEL-USER> (lquery:$ *PDELFINO-PARSED* "title" (serialize))
#("<title>Pedro Delfino</title>")
```

Comment: could use `lquery:$1` to select one element, so lquery can return the single element without wrapping it in an array.

Answer (score 2):

The text of the title is in its child text-node.

`(plump:text (plump:first-child (aref (clss:select "title" (plump:parse  (dex:get "http://www.pdelfino.com.br"))) 0)))` will return that text in this example.